# Office365 Calendar API - Invites not sent when creating event from AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ms-office, office365, office365api

I'm working on an app that integrates with the Office365 API, and I've come across a puzzling bit of behavior:  When trying to create new calendar events, invites are not sent to the other attendees if the event creation request comes from an AWS server; the event is created successfully and it shows up in the Organizer's calendar with all the intended invitees, but they're never notified.

To test this, I've sent identical curl requests from a bunch of different locations: my local machine, non-aws servers, aws servers.  In the first 2 cases, the invites come through correctly, in the last, no invite is generated.

Example curl request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer [redacted]" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Subject":"Test", "Location":{"DisplayName":"Location"},"Start":{"DateTime":"2016-04-03T17:00:00","TimeZone":"Eastern Standard Time"},"End":{"DateTime":"2016-04-03T19:00:00","TimeZone":"Eastern Standard Time"},"Attendees":[{"EmailAddress":{"Address":"test@test.com"}},{"EmailAddress":{"Address":"test2@test.com","Name":"Tester"}}],"Body":{"ContentType":"Text","Content":"Test event"}}' "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars/[calendar ID redacted]/events"
```

I'm completely stumped - the event returned from the Office365 API is the same in all cases, with no indication of failure.  The behavior is the same whether the invitee is @gmail, @hotmail, or @onmicrosoft.

Comment: When you metioned that the same REST works in your location machine and non-aws servers, were the meeting attendees same with AWS request?

Comment: Yes, I can copy and paste the same exact curl request - it works from non-AWS servers (event is added to calendar and invitation emails get sent) and doesn't work from AWS servers (event is added to calendar but invitation emails **don't** get sent).

I've reached out to MS, but haven't heard back yet.